# Cocoa Scripting Bridge and <contents> element

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, scripting-bridge

So, the application I'm trying to script has a scripting definition file that includes a <contents> element, which is an "implicitly specified container."

The question, how do I get at what's inside this element using Scripting Bridge?  Or alternatively, how do I send the Apple Event necessary to retrieve it and then transform what I get back into an SBObject?

I already tried:

```
[document nameOfKey]
document.nameofKey
[document contents]
document.contents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but I noticed that sometimes you have to use the keyword "get" in order to actually get something before you can access other parts of it. So I would try this...

```
[[document get] contents]
[[document contents] get]
```

etc. Note that "get" is an instance method of SBObject so you can find it in the docs.

Comment: Not quite, but you showed me the way.

You can send the raw FourCharCode using SBObjects elementArrayWithCode, and you get back the contents array.  So Yay.

    [document elementArrayWithCode:code]

You have to look up the code in the raw SDF file, and create it as an int but it does work.